# Google sheets How do I get a sheet name from a cell value

Tags: tabs, cell

I have a google sheet with 52 Tabs each has the date as its name. This is the same as B2 cell value on each sheet which contains 7 days across the top with the date at the top of each column.

The dates are linked from the previous sheet. Which allows me to alter the first date on the first sheet and that updates all the other dates in the whole workbook.

Problem I have is currently I have to alter each tab name by hand.

I have done this in Excel using VBA without an issue but it will not work if I open the workbook in sheets.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Tony

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function renameTabs() {
  // except these sheets
  const excludeSheetnames = ["Form Responses 1", "Summary"];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // temporary name to prevent error
  ss.getSheets().forEach((s, i) => {
    if (!excludeSheetnames.includes(s.getName())) s.setName('temporary name ' + i)
  })
  ss.getSheets().forEach(s => {
    if (!excludeSheetnames.includes(s.getName())) s.setName(s.getRange('B2').getDisplayValue())
  })
}
```

[setName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setnamename)

[forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

[includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

[getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue)